# Is there an idiom for "getting popular"?

Tags: idiom-request

I wonder how else I can put that "something is getting popular". Can anyone help?

Comment: _gaining momentum_ would be one idiom you could use.

Answer (score 4):

You could say something is “becoming **a household name.**”

> ### household name
>
> **house·hold name** (also **[house·hold word](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/household-words.html)**)
>   
> • n. a person or thing that is well known by the public 
> *I'd like to sell gazillions of books and become a household name.*
> <sub>Source: “household name.” The Oxford Pocket Dictionary of Current English. 2009. 
> Retrieved March 18, 2014 from [Encyclopedia.com](http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O999-householdname.html)</sub>

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung - Nice edit! You saved this answer from deletion, and set a good example of how to substantiate an answer.

Comment: how do we say this about a technology that's getting immensely popular?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways. A few of them are..

> something is all the rage these days. 
>   something is trending these days.  
>   something is skyrocketing (but use this with caution).

Comment: I have changed "on the rage" to "all the rage". I believe this is what you meant. Also, could you explain why to use "skyrocketing" with caution?

Comment: @nxx Thanks. Caution means the flow here. The way other two sentences go, this won't go. For instance, Mobile technology is all the rage these days; Mobile technology is trending these days but Mobile technology is skyrocketing these days won't exactly fit. It may take the original word *popularity* - The popularity of mobile technology is skyrocketing will emphasize more on its intense popularity. This is my opinion though.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. It might be helpful to work that into your answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's getting noticed; becoming fashionable; climbing the charts; it's crowd pleasing; people are favoring it; it has caught on; *it has gone viral* (that's a new one, and I like it a lot); it's leading the way; it's becoming very in-demand; people are loving it.

This a great place to use a [Thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/). You can probably find exactly what you are trying to say.

Comment: Thanks, I tried thesaurus, but I failed to come up with what exactly to search for

Comment: Try just searching for popular. Look at the words there, if a word seems like it might be right, than search for *that* word!

Answer (score 1):

For a more street-slangy idiom, try "[Blank] is *blowing up*"

This option is listed in the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=blowing%20up&defid=643270)

Answer (score 1):

"Catching on" is an old favorite.

> [catch on](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/catch-on) (BECOME POPULAR)
>   ​to become fashionable or popular:
>   Why did the electronic gadget catch on so fast?
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Please include an explanation or supporting evidence, like a dictionary entry, with your answers.